# Bash checking if a variable is set with -z while having `set -u`?

Tags: bash, scripting, variable

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail


if [ -z "$BUILD_DATE" ]; then
  export BUILD_DATE="$(date +%s%N)"
  echo "???"
else 
  echo "!!!!!!!"
fi
```

The above does not output anything as it runs into an error: `env/local-testing.sh:22: BUILD_DATE: parameter not set`.

Is there an alternative to running `set +u` and `set -u` again surrounding this conditional?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're running under `set -u` and have a variable that *might* be unset, and you would need to test whether it's empty with the `-z` test, then you can use

```
if [ -z "${BUILD_DATE:-}" ]; then
```

The `"${BUILD_DATE:-}"` would [expand to an empty string](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) if the `BUILD_DATE` variable is empty or unset.

Answer (score 3):

Use a default empty value:

```
if [ -z "${BUILD_DATE-}" ]; then
```

See *Parameter Expansion* in `man bash`. Using just `-` means an empty value is used when the variable is unset.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter expansion version is fine but difficult (for me) to remember. Test with -v works well for me in bash 5.0.3(1) on Raspbian Buster (Debian).

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
a=1
if [[ -v a ]]; then echo "a is set with value $a"; else echo "a is not set"; fi
unset a
if [[ -v a ]]; then echo "a is set with value $a"; else echo "a is not set"; fi
echo "ends"
```

output

```
a is set with value 1
a is not set
ends
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that this is slightly different from the inverse of `-z` in that `-v a` is true even if `a` is set to the empty string. But you could do `if ! [[ -v a ]] || [[ -z "$a" ]]; then echo "a is empty or unset"; fi` to do the same as `-z` while protecting against `set -u`.